# IIS Manager Disappeared from Start Menu and Administrative Tools

Tags: windows-7, iis

I am running Windows 7 64-bit and my IIS Manager disappeared from my *Start Menu* and from *Administrative Tools*. This is a new machine and it was working fine yesterday, but today it will not appear.

I have verified that IIS Manager is installed and that all of the appropriate features are checked in *Turn Windows features on or off*. I have also verified that *InetMgr.exe* does exist at *C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\InetMgr.exe* and I am able to run it from that path or by searching for "inetmgr". However, it does not display in my start menu or in the *Administrative Tools*.

Here is a snapshot of my features:

[image]

I have tried resetting IIS, turning the feature off and back on, and restarting the computer - all to no avail. Does anyone know how I can get the application back into my *Administrative Tools* and *Start Menu*?

Thanks so much for your help :)

Comment: This may help http://support.microsoft.com/?id=263121

Comment: It's not in the recycle bin, and I can add it as a shortcut. I've seen the support website and your link just takes me to the main page. I am really looking to make sure that there is nothing that I am missing or may have messed up on my machine that could have caused this.

Comment: To be honest, I don't think so but, sadly, time will tell!! If it goes again, then you know the answer and since it's not causing any real damage, I wouldn't be concerned (although it is odd)... Most nasty programs/virus's etc attack exe's or plugins... I don't think I've ever heard of a virus or similar just removing a single icon so I don't *think* that is the reason...

Comment: Can it be your antivirus ?

Comment: I don't believe so - I've never heard of anti-virus doing that, and I hadn't even added antivirus protection to the computer yet, at the time this started (brand new machine)

Comment: An antivirus once decimated half my Start menu, but that is not connected to your problem. Try [sfc /scannow](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html), the [System Update Readiness Tool for Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947821) and the [Windows 7 Upgrade Advisor](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/upgrade-advisor), as sometimes they fix a problem or two. Let us know what happens.

Comment: I'll give it a try, @harrymc. Regardless of the result,  you should post that as an answer.

Comment: OK, I did that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system is behaving in an abnormal manner, and it is hard to diagnose that error.
It seems like it is caused by some system corruption.

The following tools can diagnose and fix errors in Windows :

- [sfc /scannow](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html)
  Scans the integrity of all protected Windows 7 system files and replaces incorrect corrupted, changed/modified, or damaged versions with the correct versions if possible.
- [System Update Readiness Tool for Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947821)
  Scans for Windows corruption errors that prevent Windows updates and service packs from installing.
- [Windows 7 Upgrade Advisor](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/upgrade-advisor)
  Scans hardware, devices, and installed programs for known compatibility issues, giving guidance on how to resolve potential issues found, and recommends what to do.
- [Windows Update fixit](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/windows_update/) or [Reset Windows Update components](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971058/en-us)
  then try again to turn off the IIS Windows feature, reboot, reinstall, reboot.
- Full antivirus scan by your current product and in addition at least [Malwarebytes Anti-Malware](http://www.malwarebytes.org/lp/lp4/?gclid=CIyV0a-kt74CFSLlwgod13cAlw).

If running these tools gives no hint as to the problem, the next step is a
[Repair Install to Fix Windows 7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html),
which fixes the current installation of Windows while preserving user accounts, data, programs, and system drivers.

The last resort, to reinstall Windows from scratch, is not to be taken lightly
unless really necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, harry. I will let you know the result after I try all of the steps.

Comment: Unfortunately, the non-reinstall-windows solutions did not work for me.  Considering the fact that I can still use IIS, I'm not going to re-install Windows for this, and I'm not going to run a repair unless something else happens that makes this worse. Regardless, this was a solid answer, and I believe that it will be the most helpful in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Please note, in Administrative tools, it would have appeared as a short cut... Maybe you just need to re-add the short cut. Did you check the recycle bin? Sounds like it has been accidentally deleted, or accidental dragged into another folder.

Either way, since you can access IIS, you simply just need to re-add the shortcut.

Others who experienced the same issue found [restarting the IIS service restored the link to IIS Manager on administrative tools](http://forums.iis.net/t/1147321.aspx?IIS+Manager+doesn+t+appear).

As to why this happened? That is hard to know...

Virus's and the like typically attack applications and files, where as you have a missing shortcut... It just doesn't seem likely. For the same reason, I don't think it will be an AV programming quarantining it as you could access the program fine.

Comment: Thanks, Dave. I think I will put a bounty on this one when it becomes eligible to see if anyone knows what went wrong - I'm really stumped.

Comment: I should also add that, unfortunately, restarting IIS did not solve the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can reinstall it using dsim command as here http://forums.iis.net/t/1176358.aspx?Installing+using+DISM
Even you can use dsim to use alternate soruce path. 
The question as harrymc told in a previous post is why it isn´t there.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding your reference to @harrymc's explanation of why this is happening. Regardless, reinstalling via DSIM shouldn't have any different effect, but I attempted it regardless. As expected, the result was the same.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is super old, but thought I'd share my experience on what causes this to happen.  Was going to leave it as a comment, but don't have enough points yet.

One of the other admins dragged the icon off of the admin tools menu onto their desktop, which caused it to remove it from the menu.